# How to make Hazelcast Management Center find its Nodes in docker?

Tags: docker, hazelcast

I'm trying to set-up hazelcast and the management center for developement using docker. Unfortunately the management center does not find the hazelcast node.

I startet hazelcast and the management center on my machine as instructed here https://hub.docker.com/r/hazelcast/hazelcast

I do geht the following message when I enter the management center:

[image]

I tried to enter the missing information in the form like this:

[image]

but I don't find the correct values to get this working.
Any ideas whats wrong?

I used this commands to start docker:

```
docker run -e JAVA_OPTS="-Dhazelcast.local.publicAddress=162.168.1.136:5701" -p 5701:5701 hazelcast/hazelcast:3.12.5
docker run -e MC_INIT_CMD="./mc-conf.sh cluster add -H=/data -ma 192.168.1.136:5701 -cn dev" -p 8080:8080 hazelcast/management-center:3.12.5
```

This gives the following output, which looks fine to me:

```
ue73011@K57176 ~                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
$ docker run -e JAVA_OPTS="-Dhazelcast.local.publicAddress=162.168.1.136:5701" -p 5701:5701 hazelcast/hazelcast:3.12.5                                                                                                                     
+ exec java -server -Dhazelcast.mancenter.enabled=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/hazelcast/logging.properties -Dhazelcast.local.publicAddress=162.168.1.136:5701 com.hazelcast.core.server.Star
tServer                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
########################################                                                                                                                                                                                                   
# JAVA_OPTS=-Dhazelcast.mancenter.enabled=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/hazelcast/logging.properties -Dhazelcast.local.publicAddress=162.168.1.136:5701                                       
# CLASSPATH=/opt/hazelcast/*:/opt/hazelcast/lib/*                                                                                                                                                                                          
# starting now....                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
########################################                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Apr 29, 2020 4:15:20 AM com.hazelcast.config.AbstractConfigLocator                                                                                                                                                                         
INFO: Loading 'hazelcast.xml' from the working directory.                                                                                                                                                                                  
Apr 29, 2020 4:15:21 AM com.hazelcast.config.ConfigReplacerHelper                                                                                                                                                                          
WARNING: Could not find a replacement for '${hazelcast.mancenter.url}' on node 'null'                                                                                                                                                      
Apr 29, 2020 4:15:21 AM com.hazelcast.config.AbstractXmlConfigHelper                                                                                                                                                                       
WARNING: Name of the hazelcast schema location is incorrect, using default                                                                                                                                                                 
Apr 29, 2020 4:15:21 AM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker                                                                                                                                                                               
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [3.12.5] Prefer IPv4 stack is true, prefer IPv6 addresses is false                                                                                                                                                     
Apr 29, 2020 4:15:21 AM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker                                                                                                                                                                               
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [3.12.5] Picked [172.17.0.2]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0.0.0.0,localport=5701], bind any local is true                                                                                                     
Apr 29, 2020 4:15:21 AM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker                                                                                                                                                                               
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [3.12.5] Using public address: [162.168.1.136]:5701                                                                                                                                                                    
Apr 29, 2020 4:15:21 AM com.hazelcast.system                                                                                                                                                                                               
INFO: [162.168.1.136]:5701 [dev] [3.12.5] Hazelcast 3.12.5 (20191210 - 294ff46) starting at [162.168.1.136]:5701                                                                                                                           
Apr 29, 2020 4:15:21 AM com.hazelcast.system                                                                                                                                                                                               
INFO: [162.168.1.136]:5701 [dev] [3.12.5] Copyright (c) 2008-2019, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.                                                                                                                                    
Apr 29, 2020 4:15:21 AM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.BackpressureRegulator                                                                                                                                                 
INFO: [162.168.1.136]:5701 [dev] [3.12.5] Backpressure is disabled                                                                                                                                                                         
Apr 29, 2020 4:15:22 AM com.hazelcast.instance.Node                                                                                                                                                                                        
INFO: [162.168.1.136]:5701 [dev] [3.12.5] Creating MulticastJoiner                                                                                                                                                                         
Apr 29, 2020 4:15:22 AM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl                                                                                                                                                
INFO: [162.168.1.136]:5701 [dev] [3.12.5] Starting 2 partition threads and 3 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)                                                                                                              
Apr 29, 2020 4:15:22 AM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics                                                                                                                                                                     
INFO: [162.168.1.136]:5701 [dev] [3.12.5] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.                                                                                                   
Apr 29, 2020 4:15:22 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService                                                                                                                                                                                
INFO: [162.168.1.136]:5701 [dev] [3.12.5] [162.168.1.136]:5701 is STARTING                                                                                                                                                                 
Apr 29, 2020 4:15:25 AM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.ClusterService                                                                                                                                                                      
INFO: [162.168.1.136]:5701 [dev] [3.12.5]                                                                                                                                                                                                  

Members {size:1, ver:1} [                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        Member [162.168.1.136]:5701 - 84049f1a-2343-42ab-85b8-5edba08567b5 this                                                                                                                                                            
]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

Apr 29, 2020 4:15:25 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService                                                                                                                                                                                
INFO: [162.168.1.136]:5701 [dev] [3.12.5] [162.168.1.136]:5701 is STARTED                                                                                                                                                                  

ue73011@K57176 ~                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
$ docker run -e MC_INIT_CMD="./mc-conf.sh cluster add -H=/data -ma 192.168.1.136:5701 -cn dev" -p 8080:8080 hazelcast/management-center:3.12.5                                                                                              
########################################                                                                                                                                                                                                   
# JAVA_OPTS=-Dhazelcast.mancenter.home=/data -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true                                                                                                                                                               
# MC_CLASSPATH=/opt/hazelcast/mancenter/hazelcast-mancenter-3.12.5.war                                                                                                                                                                     
# starting now....                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
########################################                                                                                                                                                                                                   
+ exec java --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -server -Dhazelcast.mancenter.home=/data -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -cp /opt/hazelcast/mancenter/hazelcast-mancenter-3.12.5.war Launcher 8080 8443 hazelcast-mancenter        
2020-04-29 04:16:51 [main] INFO  c.h.webmonitor.config.BuildInfo - Management Center 3.12.5                                                                                                                                                
2020-04-29 04:16:55 [main] INFO  c.h.w.storage.DiskUsageMonitor - Monitoring /data [mode=purge, interval=1000ms, limit=512 MB]                                                                                                             
2020-04-29 04:17:07 [main] INFO  c.h.webmonitor.config.SqlDbConfig - Checking DB for required migrations.                                                                                                                                  
2020-04-29 04:17:08 [main] INFO  c.h.webmonitor.config.SqlDbConfig - Number of applied DB migrations: 2.                                                                                                                                   
2020-04-29 04:17:08 [main] INFO  c.h.w.s.s.impl.DisableLoginStrategy - Login will be disabled for 5 seconds after 3 failed login attempts. For every 3 consecutive failed login attempts, disable period will be multiplied by 10.
2020-04-29 04:17:10 [main] INFO  Launcher - Hazelcast Management Center successfully started at http://localhost:8080/hazelcast-mancenter
```

Comment: Can you try adding a `:` before the port number: `-ma 192.168.1.1365701`?

Comment: God spot! I checked back, the `:` just disappeared somehow when I created the post. It's correct now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the commands for Hazelcast (and Management Center) version `4.0`, but you actually run images `3.12.5`. The mechanism how Management Center is connected has changed. So you need to either use the most recent version or apply the [instructions for 3.12.5](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-docker/tree/v3.12.5#hazelcast-enterprise-hello-world), like this:

```
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 hazelcast/management-center:3.12.5
$ docker run -p 5701:5701 -e MANCENTER_URL="http://<host_ip>:8080/hazelcast-mancenter" -e JAVA_OPTS="-Dhazelcast.local.publicAddress=<host_ip>:5701" hazelcast/hazelcast:3.12.5
```